# Analyze a Time Series

Tags: sql, oracle

```
I am inserting data into a table with date/time column. 

I want to find speed of inserts during a particular duration as follows :

Duration         # of Records
1:00pm - 2:00PM    1000
2:00pm - 3:00PM    1400
.......................
11:00PM- 12:00     1100

Though I can find above by repeatedly executing follows:

 select count(*) from table_A where insert_date between 1:00pm and 2:00pm
```

Is there Oracle supplied package/function which can produce above report - without having to execute separate statements ?

Comment: `group by trunc(dt, 'hh')`

Comment: Works great....

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of examples. To get "sparse" results, ie, just the data that exists within the table, you simply use TRUNC

```
SQL> create table data ( d date );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into data
  2  select date '2022-02-10' + dbms_random.normal/10
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 10000;

10000 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> select trunc(d,'HH24'), count(*)
  2  from data
  3  group by trunc(d,'HH24')
  4  order by 1;

TRUNC(D,'HH24')       COUNT(*)
------------------- ----------
09/02/2022 13:00:00          1
09/02/2022 15:00:00          4
09/02/2022 16:00:00         10
09/02/2022 17:00:00         40
09/02/2022 18:00:00        126
09/02/2022 19:00:00        282
09/02/2022 20:00:00        595
09/02/2022 21:00:00        948
09/02/2022 22:00:00       1389
09/02/2022 23:00:00       1577
10/02/2022 00:00:00       1609
10/02/2022 01:00:00       1362
10/02/2022 02:00:00        956
10/02/2022 03:00:00        624
10/02/2022 04:00:00        281
10/02/2022 05:00:00        134
10/02/2022 06:00:00         43
10/02/2022 07:00:00         16
10/02/2022 08:00:00          2
10/02/2022 10:00:00          1

20 rows selected.
```

If you need to get ALL hours, even if there was no data for a given hour, you can OUTER JOIN the raw data to a synthetic list of rows with all hours for the desired range, eg

```
SQL> with full_range as
  2   ( select date '2022-02-09' + rownum/24 hr
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 48
  5   ),
  6  raw_data as
  7  ( select trunc(d,'HH24') dhr, count(*) cnt
  8  from data
  9  group by trunc(d,'HH24')
 10  )
 11  select full_range.hr, raw_data.cnt
 12  from raw_data, full_range
 13  where full_range.hr = raw_data.dhr(+)
 14  order by  1;

HR                         CNT
------------------- ----------
09/02/2022 01:00:00
09/02/2022 02:00:00
09/02/2022 03:00:00
09/02/2022 04:00:00
09/02/2022 05:00:00
09/02/2022 06:00:00
09/02/2022 07:00:00
09/02/2022 08:00:00
09/02/2022 09:00:00
09/02/2022 10:00:00
09/02/2022 11:00:00
09/02/2022 12:00:00
09/02/2022 13:00:00          1
09/02/2022 14:00:00
09/02/2022 15:00:00          4
09/02/2022 16:00:00         10
09/02/2022 17:00:00         40
09/02/2022 18:00:00        126
09/02/2022 19:00:00        282
09/02/2022 20:00:00        595
09/02/2022 21:00:00        948
09/02/2022 22:00:00       1389
09/02/2022 23:00:00       1577
10/02/2022 00:00:00       1609
10/02/2022 01:00:00       1362
10/02/2022 02:00:00        956
10/02/2022 03:00:00        624
10/02/2022 04:00:00        281
10/02/2022 05:00:00        134
10/02/2022 06:00:00         43
10/02/2022 07:00:00         16
10/02/2022 08:00:00          2
10/02/2022 09:00:00
10/02/2022 10:00:00          1
10/02/2022 11:00:00
10/02/2022 12:00:00
10/02/2022 13:00:00
10/02/2022 14:00:00
10/02/2022 15:00:00
10/02/2022 16:00:00
10/02/2022 17:00:00
10/02/2022 18:00:00
10/02/2022 19:00:00
10/02/2022 20:00:00
10/02/2022 21:00:00
10/02/2022 22:00:00
10/02/2022 23:00:00
11/02/2022 00:00:00

48 rows selected.
```